# would it be ok to create an instantiate an object in another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, model-view-controller, controller

I have a controller for customer.  In the new action, I redirect to another page, which belong to the pages controller

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    redirect_to register_path
  end
```

Would it be possible to create the object in the registration action like this?

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController        
  def registration
    @customer = Customer.new
  end
end
```

Comment: sure you can, but it's not that restful

Comment: You can technically instantiate objects anywhere you want to, although it may not follow some best practices like REST (as @kingguy suggested). What are you trying to do? Are you trying to change the `/customers/new` route to `/registration` or something? Because you should tweak `config/routes.rb` if that's the case.

Comment: I can't really create object in customer controller as I'm trying to render the new action from the registration view, I made new action view as a partial.The intention of having the registration view is to contain the code for creating tabs and when user click on appropriate tab it would render appropriate sign up view

Comment: If I am reading that correctly, what I would normally do is have the HTML for the tabs in a partial and include (`render`) that partial in customers/new.html.erb. Each of the others tabs is probably a different controller/action and they would each `<%= render 'application/special_tabs' %>`. Unless … is the content for all the tabs contained in a single HTML page in the browser? Then as the user clicks a different tab, you are just using JavaScript to hide/show sections without a page load?

Comment: Well, the way I did it is create a intermediate page call registration page which is the registration action in pages controller, then I generate html code to create 2 tabs in that registration file, then render new action for each type of user as the content of each tabs when user click on tabs. I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it though, since I can't figure out the logic to pass object through the registration page and into each new partial

Comment: Okay, so there's no real 'neat' way to do structure that. You have a page containing 'stuff' from two different resources (a Customer, and something else). I'll elaborate in an answer with some examples.

Comment: Thank, I needed an example to at least point me to a right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the setup is something like this: you have models in your application for a Customer and, say, an Agent. Your website users register as either and the desire is to have a single HTML page (URL) with both options available. They choose which one they are and submit some fields, say name/email/password. To keep it simple, without bothering with JavaScript to hide things behind tabs, you have something like:

```
**Customer**
Name: ___________
Email: __________
Password: _______
[Submit]

**Agent**
Name: ___________
Email: __________
Password: _______
[Submit]
```

You have a few options here to avoid your guilty feeling in the Rails controllers:

1. Go heavy client-side JavaScript. Don't have the `new` actions on the controllers. The JavaScript creates the page elements. The create action becomes a JSON API endpoint, thereby avoiding the problem in the Ruby application. This is obviously a significant architectural deviation from where I think you are today.
2. Use a little bit of JavaScript to dynamically load the correct 'partial' into the DOM when the user switches between the options. Avoids the underlying problem in the question by effectively separating the 'pages' out to the two controllers. The Pages→registration action does not need to set any instance variables for the view. The JavaScript deals with the partial loading. (see 'link_to' and the 'remote' option)
3. Don't include both forms in the same HTML page, just default to one, say the *Customer* one, and provide a link to navigate to the *Agent* one, e.g. a link in a tab, or a plain link like "Not a Customer? Register as an Agent." In this scenario, you have a neat mapping to the Ruby MVC design, each of the pages are just the `new` action of its relevant controller. The downside is a page load to change between the two options. This is the simplest, plainest choice … if you can get the boss to agree to the UX. PS: if you are using turbolinks, then the 'feel' of this option in the browser will be not far from option (2).
4. Stick to your design

Keep in mind that you will have difficultly dealing with error conditions and messages with option (4). You can do it, but the code won't be simple or easy to maintain.

If option (4) is a must, one simplification can be the `create` actions on each of the controllers rendering their own `new` in case of an error. If you submit the 'Agent' form from your starting page, with errors, to the Agents→create action, that action finishes with a `render 'new'` to show the user the Agents→new page. No 'customer' form is visible. You could then add a sprinkle of option (3) in there with a "Not an Agent? Register as a Customer." link under the form. Doing this greatly simplifies your error handling.

Which then leads to a suggestion for your original problem. Cheat. Don't have an `@customer` instance variable for the `new` actions (or the `registration` action). Use partials for the customer and agent forms, and pass in a new object to `form_for`, e.g.

---

pages/registration.html.erb

```
<%= render 'customers/new_form' %>
<%= render 'agents/new_form' %>
```

---

customers/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'customers/new_form' %>
```

---

customers/_new_form.html.erb

```
<% form_for Customer.new do |f| %>
  <%# include the inputs shared with the edit action %>
  <%= render 'fields', f %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

customers/_fields.html.erb

```
<%# 'f' is one of the locals passed to the partial %>
<% f.input_field :name %>
<% f.email_field :email %>
<% f.password_field :password %>
```

---

customers/edit.html.erb

```
<% form_form @customer do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', f %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

… then you would follow the same pattern for:

- agents/new.html.erb
- agents/_new_form.html.erb
- agents/_fields.html.erb
- agents/edit.html.erb

Comment: Thank a lot for this complete explanation